# How is circular buffer used for spilling process in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

From "Hadoop the definitive guide"
[**Each map task has a circular memory buffer that it writes the output to. The buffer is
100 MB by default, a size that can be tuned by changing the io.sort.mb property. When
the contents of the buffer reaches a certain threshold size (io.sort.spill.percent,
which has the default 0.80, or 80%), a background thread will start to spill the contents
to disk**]

Question here is that since each map task works on a single input split (which more or less would be equal to the size of HDFS block i.e 64 MB), the condition for spilling back to the disk shall never arose. Am i missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume the Split Size or the Block size would be 64 MB? Practically I have seen having a small Block size reduces the performance (For the scale of data I analyse). I have seen better performance with block size/ split size of 256MB in my use case.

Coming back to your question,
Having Way too many Mappers is also an overhead on the framework. Going by the use case mentioned in the question we might not be spilling keys,values from the 100 MB circular Buffer. But consider these case where split-size is 64MB and the Mapper does some calculations based on the input and emits additional calculation results as a part of Map output, there are chances that the Map output can be more than the configured circular buffer size. Another use case we have 64 MB of block-compressed data the data just bursts up in size when processing. Considers mappers which will fetch additional data from "Side Data Distribution", "distributed cache" in the Map phase.

Just an additional Note:
From my experience I can clearly say that when we work on/with a framework the default configurations will never suit our requirements. We need to tweak and tune the system to give us the best possible performance.

Comment: Ok ! I understand that large block size would certainly invoke this condition. But large block size will also increase number of disk I/O due to multiple spills. How is this trade off taken into account ?

Comment: If the block size is large and you observe that the bottle neck for the performance is at the buffer spill to disk you need to: Option1)change the split size to a smaller value than the block size. Helps is reducing the buffer spill over. Option2) If you have more memory to spare increase the io.sort.mb memory.